# difference between も and でも when used with the て-form

Tags: particles, て-form

First of all, is there such a pattern as て-form + でも? I can't find it in my grammar dictionary. If there is, is it related to the て-form + も pattern, meaning something like "even if"? What is the difference?

Comment: I think the difference is: ~てでも is more like "even by ~~ing", while ~ても is more like "even if". You can say 卑劣な手段を使っ"てでも"優勝するぞ・卑劣な手段を使っ"ても"優勝するぞ but you don't say 嵐が来"てでも"仕事に出かけるぞ or 死ん"ででも"君と離れないよ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positive, to all of your questions.

> 10万円出してでも買いたい本
>   'a book one wants to buy even by paying 100,000 yen.'

Comment: If anyone feels discomfort or offence, please complain, and I will change the example.

Comment: Hmm maybe カンニングしてでも合格したい大学... 法を犯してでも成し遂げたい復讐... 体を売ってでも現金を手に入れようと... 人を殺してでも...sorry maybe these are even worse...^^; How about 体を張ってでも守りたいひと？

Comment: I changed it to a peaceful one.

Comment: @sawa, the english translation 'a book one wants to buy even by offering 100,000 yen' is nonsensical. Does the sentence in Japanese have this quality? Is the subject wanting to buy the book the same subject who is offering the money?

Comment: @yadokari I do not know about the quality you mention but it is perfectly fine in Japanese. Yes they are the same person. What if you replace "offer" with "pay"?

Comment: I am trying to grasp the meaning as the english is not clear. Is this close? - A book I want to buy even if I have to spend 100,000 yen - (i changed the subject to "I" to make it easier). I don't know if my "if" insertion is adding meaning that is not there.

Comment: Close in meaning but I think my original is faithful to the Japanese.