# The difference between Verbても and Verbてでも

Tags: particles, particle-でも

The difference between `Verbても` and `Verbてでも` was discussed in a thread [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/difference-between-%E3%82%82-and-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-when-used-with-the-%E3%81%A6-form) but I felt it wasn't fully clarified there. This difference is rarely mentioned in textbooks, as far as I can tell. So I thought it should be explored a little more. Maybe we can clarify how the English translations would differ between these two sentences.

> **1:** 体を張っ**てでも**反対する。
>   **2:** 体を張っ**ても**反対する。

I am assuming that using `でも` introduces a weakening of volition, ie "even if I do **something like** risking my life", as opposed to a more definite "even I risk my life". But perhaps there is a more subtle nuance. How would you translate these sentences to highlight the distinction?

Comment: I can't vouch for the accuracy of this, but my grammar book (A handbook of Japanese Grammar patterns for Teachers and Learners -- Group Jammassy) says of てでも: "Used to indicate tough measures for dealing with a situation. Accompanied by expressions of strong intent or desire, it conveys a determination to accomplish something even by employing extreme measures". This seems to fit with your example sentence at least.

Comment: That also fits another source I found: "体を張ってでも守ってやるという覚悟が必要です。"

Comment: @user3856370 My case fits your definition also: "無理をしてでも探し出す". I find the main answer confusing compared to your textbook's explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

体を張ってでも反対する means that the one who 体を張る is identical to the one who 反対する while 体を張っても反対する means that those two are different.

- 体を張ってでも反対する： I would rather risk my own body to oppose it.
- 体を張っても反対する： I oppose it even if you risk your own body.

Edit:

> couldn't 体を張っても反対する be interpreted as "even if I risk my life (body)"?

Practically yes, but that sounds slip of saying てでも, after all.

It's not that you can't bridge clauses by the same agant with ても. (**edit**) For example, you can say 図書館に行っても本を読まない. However, you can't link actions that share the same orientation, in other words, direction of volition (will) with **paradoxical conjunction** ても.

So, you have to remove volitional element from the verb in the clause with ても by changing it to a subjunctive mood, i.e. 体を張る → 体を張ることになる, as a whole, 体を張ることになっても, which is almost the same as てでも.

Comment: couldn't 体を張っても反対する be interpreted as "even if I risk my life (body)"? Something like 維持でも which the speaker can use to refer to his own actions.

Comment: ↑ I hate to be that guy but 維持でも → 意地でも. And I agree with kandyman in that both are used in this way, although I feel the second one should not be used in this sense at all (regardless of who is speaking) from a strict grammatical point of view.

Comment: In that case, what would be the appropriate way to express "Even if I risk my life, I will oppose you" using the て form? Or is it just unnatural to express it that way.

Comment: @kandyman The てでも form. I can't find any good source on this, but I believe the second one is mostly colloquial (or at least it was originally).

Comment: It might be colloquial, I'm not sure. However the sources I found in a few corpora were often older texts from the 1920s and 1930s. So perhaps this is a somewhat outdated phrase. I was curious as to whether there was a different nuance between the two.

Comment: also, I'm not convinced that the speaker can't be referring to himself. See this sentence: "体を張ってでも守ってやるという覚悟が必要です。" from a source called 思春期のこころの病気. I think the speaker intends to 守る even if it is damaging to themselves, not someone else.

Comment: @kandyman By "second one" I meant the lower one in the OP, i.e. the ても form. The てでも form is what I believe is the only grammatically correct form, at least strictly speaking, while I'm relatively certain that the ても form (in this "Even if I have to (x), I will (y)" usage) was at least originally used exclusively in colloquial contexts.

Comment: why is 体を張っても反対する grammatically incorrect?